# RedirectToAction inside a action method that creates a new object in the entity in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirecttoaction

I have a action method that is following:

```
    public ActionResult CreateNKITemplate(int id)
    {
        var goalcard = createNKIRep.GetGoalCardByID(id);
        createNKIRep.CreateTemplate(goalcard);

        return View();
    }
```

This action method will create a new GoalCard object inside my GoalCard Entity which means it will basicly generate an ID.

Inside CreateTemplate action method  I want to remove `return View();` and add `return RedirectToAction` so it redirects to the new GoalCard object id that was created

I want to redirect the new GoalCard object ID to:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   // code..
}
```

How can I do this?

Basicly: Copy and create a new Object and then redirect the new object id to this edit action method that takes Id as parameter.

**UPDATE:**

Accepted Answer solution:

```
   public ActionResult CreateNKITemplate(int id)
    {
       var goalcard = createNKIRep.GetGoalCardByID(id);
       var copygoalcard = createNKIRep.CreateTemplate(goalcard);
       var GoalCardCopyID = copygoalcard.Id;

       return RedirectToAction(
              "Edit", // Action name
              "CreateNKI", // Controller name
              new { id = GoalCardCopyID }); // Route values

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Well, the definition for `RedirectToAction` is.

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues
)
```

So we just fill in your values.

```
RedirectToAction(
    "Edit",                // Action name
    "GoalCardController",  // Controller name
    new { id = gcId }      // Route values
)
```

Note that the above  code assumes that your controller is called `GoalCardController` and that the id is stored in a variable called `gcId`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for this?

```
public ActionResult CreateNKITemplate(int id)
{
    var goalcard = createNKIRep.GetGoalCardByID(id);
    createNKIRep.CreateTemplate(goalcard);

    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = id});
}
```

This will redirect you and give the id as a parameter, you are able to add multiple parameters in the same way, just divided by ",".

You can also chance the path to another controller if you want to.